# TinyXML can't read some files

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I can load a file `applicationHost.config`

```
<Parent>
    <Child1 test="program" />    
    <Child2>
        <Node number="123456789" />      
    </Child2>
    <Child3>        
        <Hello World="!!!" />
    </Child3>    
</Parent>
```

just fine in one folder `C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp` but if I move that file to another folder `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`

I get a "Failed to open file" with erroreRow=0 and errorCol=0

Code snippet:

```
    std::string fileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationHost.config";
    //fileName = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\temp\\applicationHost.config";

    std::string output;
    TiXmlDocument doc;

    if(doc.LoadFile(fileName))
```

As you can see I am using an absolute path, so there shouldn't be any worry about relative directories. Also, the file in both instances have read-only UNCHECKED, and users set to EVERYONE with full control on.

Why can't I load the file when it's in `C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationHost.config`

Comment: Is this x86 binary on x64 system?

Comment: i think it might, why would that cause an issue?

Comment: Because of Windows file redirection - it maps 64bit windows\syswow64 to 32bit windows\system32. Hence, if you put a file in 64bit windows\system32 it will not be found in 32bit.

Comment: could you provide a fix, or point me in the direction of ways around this?

Comment: You may either compile your program for 64bit or use `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` to disable this feature (use MSDN for reference)